# Safer way to process form in php?

Tags: php, security, overflow

Is it safe to do smth like this in first if on the page `ctype_digit(base64_decode(trim($_POST['id'])` or i should first create variable inside if and assign trim(`$_POST['id']`) to it because they might have put some crazy thing in it that might overflow `base64_decode` or `ctype_digit` for example or i am overemphasizing?

Comment: Uhm, why do you need it at all?

Comment: The answer to all your questions in this post is: "YES!" all of them. Never trust that what you recieve from the user matches with any valid input by default. It's a string of any random content and you should check all conditions before you take this string along into the rest of your code.

Comment: Why on the Earth you're doing base64_decode here?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel can you explain your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you are being careful enough by doing that. However, in most cases the correct way to code would be to create a variable, like $id, and assign it the value of your post variable. This is because allot of developers have to work with templates, and as a PHP programmer your task would be to take post / get input and database rows, and make them available to templates as easy to access variables and arrays.

Your example makes your script safe when you are expecting a numerical id. If you are expecting a string, usually to be used in an SQL statement, then you will need to take further steps. Even the cleanest string can be used for SQL injection. That's where prepared statements should be used.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question I'm afraid.
Simply assigning $_POST['id'] to a variable before applying the 3 functions to it would not make any difference.
However, you should first validate that $_POST['id'] is actually set (or you'll get a notice) and you should always validate that the incoming data (value in $_POST['id']) is actually valid (and can not induce attacks if it contains a malicious value) before using it.

Comment: is there some standard way to validate data from forms?

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid of huge data inputs just add an strlen before you decode it, in that way you won't need to worry about overflowing it. And you should always check the data before using in near a database.

Comment: Don't only protect your DB; XSS might also be possible, even though it can't harm your DB.

Comment: Can you do XSS trough firebug?